# How to get exim4's smtp and pop3/imap server name and settings?

Tags: email, configuration, email-server, exim, debian-wheezy

I'm missing exim4 configuration file in `/etc/exim/exim4.conf`.

`dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` runs OK and sending/receiving emails is also OK. I just don't know where is the configuration saved.

The main thing is that I need to find out what to fill to Thunderbird's setup email fields (into smtp field and imap/pop3 field), because I cannot find the name of my smtp and imap/pop3 server. Where can I get it please?

**EDIT:** I've set mail.example.com when I was running configuration, but setting this to Thunderbird doesn't work.

**EDIT2:** In `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` I've found some configuration, but nothing about smtp/imap/pop3:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='example.com; localhost'
dc_local_interfaces='<MY_IP_ADDRESS> ; 127.0.0.1 ; ::1'
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Comment: exim doesn't do imap/pop3.  You need another daemon for that.  Perhaps dovecod?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your server directly by IP address. The other possibility - is to use its domain name as far as all services are located on the same host. To find out connecting ports you have to use command `ss | egrep "(exim|dovecot)"` - you'll obtain the list of ports that services listen on. SSL/TLS is a bit more complicated, you have to perform mentioned above first.

Comment: I think you'll find you need `ss -tlp`, not plain `ss`. Note also imap/pop3 has nothing to do with exim (Zoredache already mentioned that).